# Licensing ' Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold' for a logo

Tags: fonts, logo, copyright, typefaces, font-licensing

I used "Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold" in a logo project. Now I need to deliver the original files including the font to my client. The font was free but not licensed. If necessary I will buy it before sending files but I'm confused: which license should I use for the logo?
Is the desktop version (5 computer usable) safe for the client's usage?

Answer (score 2):

If your client wants to use the font beyond the logo, he will need a licence, for sure. If he will use it on one computer, he should buy a one computer licence, if he will use it on 5, a 5 seat licence.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you want to know how to send the image as it is.

If you select the text, then right-click on it and select "create outlines", illustrator will automatically transform the text of the font into shapes as if they were done by the pen tool.

I hope this answers what you asked.

Comment: no actually my client want the font also. Can I send him that font without license. Can he use that on his website as logo??

Comment: If your client wants the font used in the logo I am pretty sure that it won't be used in a good way. Someone should guide them into what fonts they should use for different text scenarios - using the logo font is seldom the first choice.